Is the current through this transistor 0?
This is circuit below.
This gate has been connected to DC bias voltage. It's grounded because I want to analyse in small signal analysis.

Does this equation below hold?
$$-V_x g_{m1} + \frac{V_F - V_X} {r_{o1}} = 0$$

no current. Vgs < Vt

What is the threshold voltage? And...if you want to solve the DC bias problem...the small signal model is not relevant.

Your equation is for small signal. Not what you need here.

@Fred There is DC bias voltage at the gate of this transistor.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany This gate has been connected to DC bias voltage. It's grounded because I want to analyse in small signal analysis.

Another possibility is that the input voltage \$V_T < 0\$. Then, the transistor can indeed be in the strong inversion region. Since the current in the transistor is forced by the ideal current source (call that \$I_D\$), we can write a KCL at node X:
$$I_D = \frac{V_X}{R_1} + \frac{V_X - V_T}{R_2}$$
where \$V_X = -V_{GS_1}\$ is also fixed by the transistor (ignoring channel-length modulation). As you can see, there are too many opposing conditions that might simply not comply with each other. That being said, solutions to this equation might exist and an example is:
$$V_{GS_1} = 0.5\textbf{ V}, I_D = 0.5\textbf{ mA}, R_1 = 1\textbf{ k}\Omega, V_T = -1.5\textbf{ V}, R_2 = 1\textbf{ k}\Omega .$$

Edit: Let's analyze the small-signal performance for this circuit. The small-signal resistance looking into the source of the transistor (ignoring the body effect) is:
$$r_{in} = \frac{r_o + R_D}{1+g_mr_o}$$
which reduces to \$ r_{in} = \infty \$ for \$R_D = \infty\$. Thus, you can simply form a voltage divider at the input and write:
$$V_X = \frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2}V_T.$$
The changes in \$V_X\$ do change the transistor current, but that current simply circulates in the loop formed by \$g_m\$ and \$r_o\$. This gives the output voltage as:
$$V_F = V_X + r_o\cdot g_m V_X = (1+g_mr_o)V_X = \frac{R_1(1+g_mr_o)}{R_1 + R_2}V_T.$$
The schematic below illustrates how you can replace the input source with its equivalent model at node X, and verify it from there:
$$\frac{V_F}{V_X} = (1+g_mr_o) = 1 + \frac{2I_D}{(V_{GS} - V_T)\lambda I_D} \approx 66.5$$
for \$ \lambda = 0.1\textbf{ V}^{-1}, V_T = 400 \textbf{ mV} \$and the simulations suggest a gain of around 71, accurate to within 10%.


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I am not interested in DC analysis. Can you analyse in small signal analysis?

to be clear, $V_T$ is ac signal rather DC.

@kile please see the edits.

What is $R_D$? you schematics  never showed that

@kile total resistance at the drain. Your original schematic never showed it and hence, I just replaced it with infinity for an ideal current source.

There is no current. Vgs must be greater than Vt (off threshold voltage for Vgs) for an Nch MOSFET.
It should be Vgs>Vt of the device and not a voltage source called Vt applied to the source with 0V on the gate.  Now Vgs is negative which is an off state for Nch.
What is the off-current? You won't see Vt in datasheets. Instead, a tiny fixed current is specified to measure what they call Vgs(th) @ Id at some very small current which you should find to be Vgs(th) at Id = Id(max) / 1000 or less and is not a fixed current for all FETs.

This gate has been connected to DC bias voltage. It's grounded because I want to analyse in small signal analysis.

Then isn't Vt the wrong polarity for NFET

Actually $V_T$ doesn't have any polarity.  $V_T$ is ac signal

I assume the DC bias from drain CC put the device into saturation then the AC source should not be called Vt. (Gate threshold Vt) That amplitude of Vt for the device is not a small signal.

You're right, the name is not very great. Maybe  it should be called $V_{in}$. But here the reason why I call it because it test voltage. What kind of KCl and KVl can you get in small signal analysis?

I can't get it to conduct because this is an NFET and is not properly biased.  Where did you come up with this idea that it should work?

Page 78 (CG stage with finite transistor output resistance) from https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf

SImilar yet some discrepancies  https://i.sstatic.net/kE0Yoavb.png
